# Magit ediff range in a pretty way?

Tags: magit, git, highlighting, ediff, version-control

I need to investigate a project, with a patch made by a former student of my university. He made a series of commits on a repo, and I need to see what additions he made.

I got the list of files modified with `git diff --name-status <hash>`.

Now I want to use Magit to see, in a file, *all the lines added by the student*. Since his commits are all continuous, and end at `HEAD`, I figured out I could use Ediff range, so: `E r <initial-commit>`. Now, my question is: **is there a better, more specific way to do that**?

I'm interested, in particular, in **having the inserted lines highlighted, while still being able to see the other ones**. Ediff does that, but then I need to expand the window, and make the buffer read-only for safety. I also thought of `git blame` (`C-c M-g b`) but then I see all the commits, not just the range I'm interested in. Maybe something like `git blame`, but for ranges? Is it possible to do so in Magit?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: `git diff <initial commit>..HEAD` on the other hand, effectively shows the additions, but I can't read the rest of the file, unless I set an overshooting `-U` (context) parameter, and in any case it's not as comfortable as `git blame`.